# How to parse Excel file as variable?

Tags: xlsx

I need to parse a file which content is stored to a string variable with a value received from
reader.readAsText(file);
The problem is XLSX does not accept either "string" or "buffer" to Excel file stored by reader.readAsText(file);

```html
<input type=file onchange="handleFileSelect(event)">
<textarea id="result" cols="10" rows="10"></textarea>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function handleFileSelect(e) {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);


    reader.onload = function () {
      let workbook = XLSX.read(reader.result, {
        type: "array"
      });
      workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName) {
        let parsedRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(parsedRows);
      })
    };
  }
</script>
```

Example works -> just change `readAsText` into `readAsBinaryString` and `type: "array"` into `type: "binary"`
Is it possible to parse readAsText content?